# twitteR package stopped returning location

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, sttwitterapi

I started having problems with extracting tweets with twitteR package: I don't get "location" (that's stated in user's profile) in the output anymore and I need it for my further analysis.
I am using the exact same code as before. Can anyone help?

```
TweetFrame <- function(searchTerm, maxTweets) 
{
tweetList <- searchTwitter(searchTerm, n = maxTweets, lang = "en")

tweetDF <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tweetList, as.data.frame))

return(tweetDF[order(as.integer(tweetDF$created)), ])
}



tweetDF <-
TweetFrame("#climate OR climate change OR global warming", 20)
```

Before I would get a data frame with 20 objects and 19 variables, but now it returns only 16 variables.

[image: location should be after latitude]

Comment: That package hasn't been updated since 2015. Probably the twitter API has changed. I recommend the `rtweet` package.

Comment: @jsta thanks that may be a good option! I also found a way around this - fist get a data frame with screenNames and then access users' locations from there (using lookupUsers).

Comment: @airielo you may want to share you solution as an answer to the question in case others encounter this problem

Comment: lookup<-lookupUsers(tweetDF$screenName)
tweets_df<-twListToDF(lookup) 
new_DF<-merge(x = tweetDF, y = tweets_df, by= "screenName", all.x = TRUE)
then you can access new_DF$location